# htaccess permissions on addon domains

Tags: .htaccess

i have two domains setup one called fastcms.com and the other is called **fastautos.com**.

**fastautos.com** is based in the **/home/speedycm/public_html/fastautos/** directory on my **fastcms.com** server (acting as an add on domain)

the problem i'm having now is that i want to allow users to use the fastautos.com website but continue to restrict usage to the fastcms.com website (password request).

currently both sites ask for a passsword. i only want it to ask for a password on the fastcms.com website.

this is my htaccess file at the moment!

```
RewriteEngine on
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /home/fastcm/public_html/.htpasswd
require valid-user
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fastautos.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.fastautos.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/fastcms\.co\.uk\/fastautos\/" [R=301,L]
```

please help! many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my memory is good, you can put the `AuthType` etc into a Directory section, that is applied to one directory only.

Also, if you have not denied it, you can create .htaccess file within directories of each of your site the override general settings.

Comment: +1. `<Location>` and `<LocationMatch>` are the other possibilities.

Comment: can you please provide an example

Comment: Look at the doc : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html#basicworks . Directories section are basic apache configuration, you would not have any trouble to find tutorial on the inet. Should look like : <Directory /docroot>
     Blah blah blah
</Directory>